# Dynamic Cookies For Retrofit 2 Requests

Tags: java, retrofit2, okhttp

I've been using retrofit for quite a long time and haven't faced any serious usability issue before now. So my use case is very simple, I've to fetch an entity from another API that we're using to process a few data. Now the only issue is the service is using `Cookies` to accept entity id.

So this means that each request needs to have dynamic set of cookie associated with it. But currently I cannot see anything such that in Retrofit. I can see a old [PR](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/915), but it was rejected for unknown reason.

Can anyone from Retrofit team can help in this matter. I think it will be very helpful. If you need code examples I can provide that in an edit.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom CookieJar and set on the OkHttpClient

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cookie-jar/

```
abstract fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie>
```

> Load cookies from the jar for an HTTP request to url. This method returns a possibly empty list of cookies for the network request.

Comment: Cookies are not client specific but request specific, so I need to create cookies per call. I think this won't suffice the use case. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This also doesn't work. Think about the use case where the ID that you need to forward in the downstream API call is coming to you dynamically. In that case, the loadForRequest will not work. Check the PR that I've added. I was looking that kind of functionality.

Comment: OK, so two concurrent requests for the same url, you might have different cookies.  If you set the header manually then it will be overwritten if there are cookie headers.  You might want to not set a cookieJar on the client and manage cookies yourself in request headers.

Comment: Yes, so currently I am setting the Cookie Header to get my job done. But eventually if retrofit has something like @Cookie to mark a map as a cookie then it would make more sense, and the library manages the map of cookies, like it is doing for header-params and query params.